# Wordpress заменяет data-toggle="tab" на data="-" toggle="tab"

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

Собственно проблема в том что при подключении файла через include Wordpress заменяет в нем

```
data-toggle="tab"
```

на

```
data="-" toggle="tab"
```

Та же проблема если вставлять код с data-toggle="tab" в пост.
Как избавиться такого автоформатирования?

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что WP имеет отношение к такому поведению. М.б. браузер так видит? html валидацию проходит?

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут data нормально применяется к тегу 
Я просто начал использовать вместо

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Текст</a>
```

такие конструкции

```
<a href><div data-toggle="tab" href="#">Текст</div></a>
```

Comment: Тебе не кажется, что это называется "через жопу"?

Comment: Спасибо за честность, но вот как было догадаться о таком, мягко говоря, не стандартном html-коде по вопросу? Вот именно из-за таких ситуаций вопросы без полного кода надо закрывать с самого начала.

Comment: @РашенБеар я и валидатор с вами полностью согласны. если найду лучшее решение, то опубликую